# How would you optimize this Binary Text Classification model further? The data set is large (40000 texts)

Tags: machine-learning, python, keras, tensorflow, text-classification

I'm learning about tensorflow/keras since a couple months.
What are some methods to reduce overfitting in the later epochs or increase val. accuracy in general?
train data dim (40000,70) (reddit comments)

best results, after a lot of trial and error, so far with:

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=14000,output_dim=400,input_length=70))
model.add(keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D())
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(400, activation="relu"))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1,activation="sigmoid"))

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])

fit_model = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 10, batch_size = 128, validation_data=(x_val,y_val), verbose=1)
```

It starts to overfit after 2 epochs(val acc=0.82).

Comment: Try adding dropout layers after Dense layer. It breaks some of the connections randomly, and can reduce overfitting. Maybe you can add regularization to your loss.